# Alter existing text in etree Element object

Tags: python, elementtree, xml.etree

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <subelement1>
            subelement1 text
        </subelement1>
        <subelement2>
            subelement2 text
        </subelement2>
    </element>
</root>
```

It's my goal to parse the tree, and alter *only* the data in a particular subelement, in this case `<subelement2>`.So, where currently there exists the string `subelement2 text`, I want to be able to append data to that so that the resulting XML is as follows:

```
<root>
    <element>
       <subelement1>
                subelement1 text
       </subelement1>
       <subelement2>
                subelement2 text + my new string of text
       </subelement2>
    </element>
</root>
```

Noting, that `subelement2 text` has now become `subelement2 text + my new string of text`

---

I already can find parse the text and find `subelement2`, like so:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring('''
<root>
    <element>
        <subelement1>
            subelement1 text
        </subelement1>
        <subelement2>
            subelement2 text
        </subelement2>
    </element>
</root>
''')
el = doc.find('.//subelement2')
```

...but once I have the Element object assigned to `el`, how do I alter its text?

What I am looking for help in understanding, is the general function or approach used to alter existing text within a subelement, as in the example above.

Comment: What have you tried? Without a [mcve] we have no clue what you need help with.

Comment: We don't do your homework here. You just gave us instructions on what do and told us to do it. Show your research. We're not paid to do this, you know.

Comment: I'm asking—broadly and generally-speaking—what function is used to append data to the text of an XML element. I can't provide an example, because I don't know how to make an attempt, and can't find it in the etree documentation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wow, I feel ridiculous for not having thought to do that. That did exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: BTW, it might not have hurt -- by way of minimizing question scope and showing work -- to show that you already had code that could find the element at hand and assign a reference it to a variable, thus making it 100% clear that all an answer had to do was to show how to manipulate that previously located/assigned element.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign to the `text` attribute of the relevant element:

```
el = doc.find('.//subelement2')
el.text += ' + my new string of text'
```